# How schema is Inferring in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one `CSV` with the following data:

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME,count
United States, Romania, 1
United States, Ireland, 264
United States, India, 69
```

I was trying to understand how is this following 2nd snippet(`Snippet 2`) working? I went through the documentation of spark which says it will `not read/load data until action is called on that dataFrame`.

Here I have created schema with wrong types and it's printing correctly as I have not called any action yet. But in 2nd snippet, I have used inferSchema instead of the custom schema to load CSV. `Now my question is how I got my correct schema type without going through the data? As I have not called any action yet! Notice that I got integer type at count`

> Snippet 1

```
val myManualSchema = new StructType(Array(
      StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME", LongType, true),
      StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME", LongType, true),
      StructField("count", LongType, false) ))

    val csv2010 = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("2010-summary.csv").getFile
    spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .schema(myManualSchema)
      .load(csv2010).printSchema()

    /* OUTPUT:
    root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: long (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = true)
     */
```

> Snippet 2

```
spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .load(csv2010).printSchema()

    /* OUTPUT:
    root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
     */
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the documentation exactly states it, but, while that's guaranteed for RDDs, it's actually up to the `DataFrameReader` to avoid making any reads when loading.

In practice, the internal CSV reader in Spark does read the data when the `inferSchema` is set to `true`: see [this particular line of code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/csv/CSVInferSchema.scala#L56) which calls the `aggregate()` action on the internal RDD to infer the types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In general, `Spark will fail only at job execution time rather than DataFrame definition time`, the aggregate() function will cause an action, not transformation right?